# Find $\mathbb{E}(X+Y\mid Y-X)$ given joint pdf $f(x, y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let be $X$ and $Y$ random variables with joint probability function $f(x,y) = 4xy$ with $0<x<1$, $x<y<1$ and $-1<x<0$, $x<y<0$.

I want to find $\mathbb{E}(X+Y \mid  Y-X)$.

I tried to do a rotation of coordinates, $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$ and $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-x+y)$. However, the new function $f(u,v)$ fails with the condition:

$$\int\int_{R}f(u,v)dudv = 1,$$

where $R$ is the same region: $0<x<1$, $x<y<1$ and $-1<x<0$, $x<y<0$.

What is the correct form to solve this problem? I'm really confused.

Comment: One option is to find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y-X$ and calculate $E[X+Y\mid Y-X]=E[Y-X+2X\mid Y-X]=Y-X+2E[X\mid Y-X]$. Not sure if there is an easier way.

Comment: $R$ cannot be the same region. It is a region obtained by rotation of original  clockwise by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$, $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y-x)$ is a rotation, then 
$$
(x,y)=(0,0) \mapsto (u,v)=(0,0), 
$$
$$
(x,y)=(1,1) \mapsto (u,v)=(\sqrt{2},0), 
$$
$$
(x,y)=(0,1) \mapsto (u,v)=\left(\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}},\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right), 
$$
$$
(x,y)=(-1,-1) \mapsto (u,v)=(-\sqrt{2},0), 
$$
$$
(x,y)=(-1,0) \mapsto (u,v)=\left(-\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}},\tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\right).
$$
[image]

And the pdf $f_{U,V}(u,v)=2u^2-2v^2$ is a valid pdf inside this region. Also it is evident that 
$$
\mathbb E[X+Y\mid Y-X] = \mathbb E[\sqrt{2}U\mid \sqrt{2}V]=\sqrt{2}\mathop{\mathbb E}[U\mid V] = 0
$$
since the distribution of $U$ is symmetric for any fixed $V$.